# Post website URL on the timeline of facebook public page

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I would like to create button on my website and when clicked it should share my website URL on the timeline of my Facebook public page?
Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

Add facebook like button in your website. See (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

In your `Request` make sure you set one of your request parameters to include "status_type" as "link". Also include your URL as the "link" key in your parameters bundle.